# Multiple insert into table using stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert, bulkinsert

I have a scenario where i am trying to do mutliple insert from a stored procedure with different parameter values simultaneously into a temporary table to club all results.

My temp table is defined as-

```
create table #temptab (transaction_id varchar(20), contract_no varchar(20))
```

The SP that i am executing here returns exactly two columns with same definition as the temp table.

The code executes successfully when i SINGLE INSERT into this #temptab, eg:

```
INSERT INTO #temptab (transaction_id,contract_no)
EXEC USP_FEED_MGMT_GETFEEDTRANSACTIONLISTBYFEEDID 169049
```

It gives me an error when i am trying to MULTIPLE INSERTS with the stored procedure, tried many ways, for example:

1) Without using VALUES keyword, the one like single insert above:

```
INSERT INTO #temptab (transaction_id,contract_no)
EXEC USP_FEED_MGMT_GETFEEDTRANSACTIONLISTBYFEEDID 169049,
EXEC USP_FEED_MGMT_GETFEEDTRANSACTIONLISTBYFEEDID 169076,
EXEC USP_FEED_MGMT_GETFEEDTRANSACTIONLISTBYFEEDID 169090
```

Error text:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
```

2) Using SELECT INTO statement:

```
select * into #temptab from EXEC USP_FEED_MGMT_GETFEEDTRANSACTIONLISTBYFEEDID 169049
```

Error text:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
```

I am aware of using a OPENQUERY statement, but i am looking for a way to MULTIPLE INSERT into table using procedures with different params that return result defined as per the table structure, or if i could manually choose columns from the resultset to insert into table.

Comment: to add to my query, i am currently using **SQL Server 2008 R2** over my Windows 7. (if that anywhere possibly affects the execution)

Comment: Is it viable to convert the stored procedure into a table valued function? Otherwise you might want to create such a wrapper around the stored procedure and then you can freely select from the result of the function.

Comment: I am trying with your suggestion @CyberDude, will revert ASAP. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be simply

```
INSERT INTO #temptab (transaction_id,contract_no)
EXEC USP_FEED_MGMT_GETFEEDTRANSACTIONLISTBYFEEDID 169049

INSERT INTO #temptab (transaction_id,contract_no)
EXEC USP_FEED_MGMT_GETFEEDTRANSACTIONLISTBYFEEDID 169076

INSERT INTO #temptab (transaction_id,contract_no)
EXEC USP_FEED_MGMT_GETFEEDTRANSACTIONLISTBYFEEDID 169090
```

There is no way to union results of multiple execs, only sequential inserts one resultset by one.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt help @Andy, but in case the number of params you see above increases by 500 more values, in that case it wont be feasible to write the same line of code 500 times. Might slow down the insert process as well.

Comment: Not sure if I've understood you correctly... But if you have some logic in changing parameter for stored procedure - then definitely you can wrap this `insert into exec` lines into some loop and don't write all the calls explicitely.

Comment: Go the point, i've wrapped it up like `Select 'insert into exec' from table where column = value` and i am iterating through values in a loop.
Thanks for that help @Andy...!!! SOLVED NOW